# jquery mobile trying to open all links in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

here is my question I need to put a swipe effect to my 'li' to get next slide 
for that I have used jquery mobile.

but after using that all navigation are trying open in the same page as an ajax request.
how do i remove that effect or please suggest me how to put a swipe effect for my 'li' items 
is there any plugin for enabling swipe effect.

```
$('.slider ul li').on( 'swiperight', function() {
    $('.slider_nav a.prev').trigger('click');
});
```

this code I had used for swiping

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tags to bypass loading the content via AJAX.

Comment: put the tag jquery-mobile on your question to get more attention. And paste some of your code here.

Comment: You should add your HTML example.

Answer (score 0):

can u put "data-ajax" attribute in a link. ex:

```
<a data-ajax="false"/>
```

i am not sure its working or not